# placing data in xml file from database in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
<category categoryName="Electronics">
<product productName="Camera Lenses Collection" productID="DSCF0001"     thumbPath="thumbs/Electronics/camera_lenses_collection-other.jpg" productPrice="250.50">
<sizes>
<size>10</size>
<size>20</size>
<size>30</size>
<size>40</size>
<size>50</size>
</sizes>
<colors>
<color>Red</color>
<color>Blue</color>
<color>Green</color>
<color>Yellow</color>
<color>Pink</color>
</colors>
</category>
</product>
</products>
```

-hi i need to load data here from table via a loop. please help me
-how to generate the xml file from database?

Comment: Is there a reason you have chosen to do this using XML over JSON? The latter is much easier to use and is smaller in size as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating xml file from database is easy. You dont need loop just follow this.

Model Function

```
function getDataForXML(){
   return $query = $this->db->get('my_table');
   //Here you should note i am returning 
   //the query object instead of 
   //$query->result() or $query->result_array()
}
```

Controller

```
function get_report()
{
    $this->load->model('my_model');
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->load->helper('file');
    // get the object
    $report = $this->my_model->getDataForXML();
    //pass it to db utility function
    $new_report = $this->dbutil->xml_from_result($report);
    //Now use it to write file. write_file helper function will do it
    write_file('xml_file.xml',$new_report);
    //Done
}
```

And a new file with the name xml_file.xml is available now!

Resources

[Database Utility Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html)

And

[File Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html)